# Editing updating records mysqli

Tags: php, post, mysqli, get

My code says records updated but actually is not updated in database. Can't find loophole.Values are echoed correctly but when edited and updated gives false update.

```
if( isset($_GET['Edit']) )
{
  //<a href='edit.php?Edit=<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>'>Edit</a>
  $id = (int)$_GET['Edit'];
  $res= mysqli_query($db  ,"SELECT * FROM a WHERE id=$id");
  $row= mysqli_fetch_array($res);
}

//table columns id tid Treat
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $id = (int)($_POST['tid']);
  $Treat = (int)($_POST['tname']);
  $sql = "Update a set `Treat`='".$Treat."' where `id`=$id";

  $query = mysqli_query($db  ,$sql);

  if(!$query)
    echo mysqli_error();
  else     
    echo "Successfully Updated";
}

<tr>
  <td class="desc" align="right">Treat</td>
  <td class="desc" align="left"><input type="text" name="tname"  value="<?php echo $row['Treat'] ; ?>" class="field text ln" /></td>
</tr>

?>
```

Comment: can u get id in $id = (int)$_GET['Edit']; ? or name value in input field?

Comment: name value.....

Comment: can u get id in $id = (int)$_GET['Edit']; ?

Comment: yes.as values from id is populated.

Comment: can this data from database of that id is correct at here input field value="<?php echo $row['Treat'] ; ?>" ?

Comment: yes  data from database of that id is correct populated in input feild but when i edit and update is not updated in database

Comment: `setapptpaidamount` != `a` whats going on there?

Comment: and on the post are you sending back up `tid`? so the update knows which row to update?

Comment: check ur update query manually in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @lawrence-cherone sir, is it both the $id will conflict, and at the end of update query  $id = (int)$_GET['Edit']; will be used is it correct.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone updated as for explaining here kept as a

Comment: No it not updating there too.can you pl create query Update a set `Treat`=Abc, where `id`=2;

Comment: any comments///